# Start new fragment from dialogfragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I want to show DialogFragment in my project if database size is less then 5 (I check it in QuizFragment) and move to another fragment (ListFragment) by clicking button "OK" on dialogFragment. Both fragments are in navigation if it matters. How can I do it?

This database size check in quizFragment

```
viewModel.getRandomTranslations().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { translations ->
            binding.apply {
                if (translations.size < 5){
                    DatabaseSizeDialogFragment(translations.size).show(parentFragmentManager, "DatabaseSizeDialogFragment")
                }
}
```

This is my dialog fragment

```
class DatabaseSizeDialogFragment(
    private val databaseSize: Int
): DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.setTitle("Result Dialog")
            builder.setTitle("Your learning list size is $databaseSize. \nYou need at least 5 words to start the quiz!")
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ ->
                dismiss()
                
            }
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda

```
        viewModel.getRandomTranslations().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { translations ->
                    binding.apply {
                        if (translations.size < 5){
                            DatabaseSizeDialogFragment(
                                            {id->
                                                //move to another fragment
                                              },
                                     translations.size)
                                         .show(parentFragmentManager, "DatabaseSizeDialogFragment")
                        }
        }
```

and in dialog :

```
class DatabaseSizeDialogFragment(
    var block: (id: Int) -> Unit,private val databaseSize: Int
): DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        ...
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ ->
                dismiss()
                block.invoke(yourId)
            }
            ...
    }
}
```